# Disabling Cache in Global.ascx

Tags: asp.net, iis, browser-cache, global-asax

I have developed a pure **html 5, css and jquery** based website. Mainly targeting smart devices. Its deployed on an **IIS server**.

My client is testing this site on desktop browsers like IE, Chrome etc.

### My Problem

Whenever i make any deployments, client's browser pick pages from browser Cache. They are not picked up directly from server. I don't want to make URL changes on every html page, so browser can recognize it as a new page. Instead I thought, as this is deployed on IIS, I could make a change in one place only i.e. **Global.ascx.**

So this is what i did in Global.ascx.

```html
void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
}
```

Please note, that my application doesn't have any **web.config** as it doesn't require any.
Now browser is still picking pages from cache.

Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some testing and playing around. I added a **Web.Config** file and i used below Configurations and **it worked**.

```html
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```